# Wine: How to start native Linux app from a Windows app running in wine?

Tags: wine, gedit

I have need of a Windows application (there is no Linux version). It works perfectly under Wine on the latest Ubuntu.

However, under some circumstances, one needs to open a text editor and edit certain text files from within this Windows application. It opens the Wine Notepad application, no problem at all.

However, I would much rather need to use Gedit (or another native and more powerful text editor).

How can I edit the command (currently "C:\windows\Notepad.exe") in the Windows application to invoke/run a native Linux application like Gedit?

`start /unix /usr/bin/gedit` does nor work, nor does `start /unix "/usr/bin/gedit"`

Thank you very much in advance.

(Running Wine 1.8.7 on Ubuntu 17.04)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8205364/2072269?

Comment: Doens't work. Can't get anything to work. Please, if you have any ideas, this will help a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Ultimately, as you've likely found out, this is not possible (without some serious hackery). Wine applications are run in a sort of sandbox, and it wouldn't be possible to do that(otherwise)

The solution is *don't do that* - Whatever application you're running via wine, there is very likely a good Linux-native [alternative to](https://alternativeto.net/) it.

There might be some learning curve to learning the alternative application, but in the end, it is usually just as rewarding as using gedit instead of notepad.